# What is The Scope Of PHP Variable for MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to set up a simple comment system and I want to create the correlation between the comment and the page landed.... so when a user arrives at blog.php?id=3 they would be presented the correct comments.

What I'm doing is creating the comments table with a pageid column. The pageid column will be filled when a user posts to the page. Maybe a hidden form field? How do I make this correlation within my MYSQLI

This is what I was thinking...

```
<?php
include_once("includes/check_login_status.php");
?>
<?php
// Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Connect to the MySQL database
include "includes/db_conx.php";
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); // filter everything but numbers
// Use this var to check to see if this ID exists, if yes then get the product
// details, if no then exit this script and give message why


$sql = "UPDATE content SET views=views+1 WHERE ID=$id";
$update = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($productCount > 0) {
// get all the product details
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$article_title = $row["article_title"];
$category = $row["category"];
$readmore = $row["readmore"];
$author = $row["author"];
$date_added = $row["date_added"];
$article_content = $row["content"];
}

} else {
echo "That item does not exist.";
exit();
}

} else {
echo "Data to render this page is missing.";
exit();
}

?>

<?php 
include_once "includes/db_conx.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE pageid ="$id"ORDER BY id DESC";

$sql_comments = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_comments)){
 $name = $row["name"];
 $comment = $row["comment"];

 $commentlist .= 'name : '.$name.'<br />comment : '.$comment.'<hr>';
}
//////////////
?>
```

Is the lower half in scope of the get variable? So that I can determine what page we're on? Can this type of variable be passed thorugh a variable in the comment form?

Comment: PHP scope is PHP scope. Just because you're doing something with a database doesn't mean you're suddenly using different scoping rules. If you want something to persist between different requests/pages, then use the normal methods: hidden form fields, sessions, cookies, query parameters, etc...

Comment: I hear ya...what I'm talking about is within same page script.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd sql statement contains an error:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE pageid ="$id"ORDER BY id DESC";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE pageid =".$id."ORDER BY id DESC";
```

You might also want to change the pre_replace statement to intval:

```
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']);
```

to

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

The reason being if $_GET['id'] = 'ABC123' then preg_replace will return 123 whereas the intval will return 0.

Comment: I'm still confused as to whether or not this is in scope to do. I hadn't quite run through the code to see. I'm just looking to figure out scope a little better. What allows for the id from the actual page to be able to translate. Thanks for the heads up though.